# Plotting functions of elements in columns

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose I have a file with 3 columns x,y,z and I want to do a plot of the curve `(x , f(y(x),z(x)))`. Is it possible to do this directly from gnuplot command line?

Comment: So what are the columns y and z for? Your curve just uses x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your function, e.g.

```
f(y,z) = y**2 + z**2
```

and use the second and third column as arguments when plotting:

```
plot 'file.txt' using 1:(f($2, $3))
```

Here, `$2` is a shorthand for `column(2)`, which accessed the numerical value of the second column.